# for_each loop with dynamic block and values from tfvars

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create certain BigQuery tables with time_partitioning with the dynamic block and I want to use the values from tfvars in runtime as follows:

**./tables/tables.tf:**

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
  for_each            = var.tables == [] ? [] : toset(var.tables)
  dataset_id          = var.db_id
  deletion_protection = false
  table_id            = each.key
  
  dynamic "time_partitioning" {
    for_each = var.partitioned_tables
    content {
      type  = "DAY"
      field = time_partitioning.value.field
    }
  }
  labels = {
    environment = var.environment
    application = var.application
  }
  schema = fileexists("${path.module}/${var.db_id}/${each.key}.json") ? file("${path.module}/${var.db_id}/${each.key}.json") : null
}
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "database" {
  count                      = length(var.dbs)
  dataset_id                 = var.dbs[count.index].db_id
  friendly_name              = var.dbs[count.index].db_name
  description                = "TF"
  location                   = "US"
  delete_contents_on_destroy = var.delete_contents_on_destroy
  labels = {
    environment = var.environment
    application = var.dbs[count.index].app_name
  }
}

module "tables" {
  source      = "./tables"
  count       = length(var.dbs)
  db_id       = google_bigquery_dataset.database[count.index].dataset_id
  environment = var.environment
  application = var.dbs[count.index].app_name
  tables      = var.dbs[count.index].tables
  partitioned_tables = var.dbs[count.index].partitioned_tables
}

module "iam" {
  source      = "./iam"
  count       = length(var.dbs)
  db_id       = google_bigquery_dataset.database[count.index].dataset_id
  iam_members = var.dbs[count.index].iam_members
}
```

**dev.tfvars:**

```
region     = "us-central1"
project_id = "some-project"
dbs = [
  {
    db_id    = "dataset1"
    db_name  = "dataset1"
    app_name = "hello"
    iam_members = [
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
        member = "serviceAccount:ser-sa@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      }
    ]
    tables = ["daily_inventory", "dc_inventory", "products", "daily_sales", "planned_inventory", "stores", "stores_in_program"]
    partitioned_tables = [
      {
        table = "daily_sales"
        field = "sales_timestamp"
      },
      {
        table = "daily_inventory"
        field = "inventory_timestamp"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    db_id    = "dataset2"
    db_name  = "dataset2"
    app_name = "hello"
    iam_members = [
      {
        role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
        member = "serviceAccount:ser-sa@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
    ]
    tables = []
  }
]
environment                = "development"
delete_contents_on_destroy = true
```

var.dbs is type = list(any)

Getting:

> The given value is not suitable for var.dbs declared at
> variables.tf:9,1-15: all list elements must have the same type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the full value of `dbs`? Why did you crop it if this is the reason for the error?

Comment: Hey Marcin, I've added the full value for dbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(any)` does not mean that you can have elements of "any" type in your list. All elements must have **same type**, and you can't mix types, as you do now (i.e. second element is missing `partitioned_tables`). `any` only means that TF will infer the single type for the elements, but all elements must be of that single type. So you have three choices:

1. remove `type = list(any)`
2. Fully define your type with `optional` arguments, instead of using `any`
3. Add `partitioned_tables` to the second element:

```
[
    {
      db_id    = "dataset1"
      db_name  = "dataset1"
      app_name = "hello"
      iam_members = [
        {
          role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
          member = "serviceAccount:ser-sa@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        }
      ]
      tables = ["daily_inventory", "dc_inventory", "products", "daily_sales", "planned_inventory", "stores", "stores_in_program"]
      partitioned_tables = [
        {
          table = "daily_sales"
          field = "sales_timestamp"
        },
        {
          table = "daily_inventory"
          field = "inventory_timestamp"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      db_id    = "dataset2"
      db_name  = "dataset2"
      app_name = "hello"
      iam_members = [
        {
          role   = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
          member = "serviceAccount:ser-sa@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }
      ]
      partitioned_tables = []
      tables = []
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it seems like I got through the initial problem but I am now facing a different issue, TF is trying to now add ```time_partitioning``` to all of the tables after ```tables =```  , ignoring the ```partitioned_tables = [ { table = "daily_sales", field = "inventory_timestamp"}]``` for example. I want to add the partitioning only for the specific table in the element. Any idea why?

Comment: https://o.remove.bg/uploads/e8239088-e555-4d49-9aeb-fe45a2684297/image.png

Comment: @MassHysteria No problem. For the new issue, I would suggest making new SO question with specific details.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by making tables a map instead of list and then referencing each.value.id in the map for partitioning. Thanks for the help